# Can not install Laravel Cashier

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-cashier

I was using `php5.5.12`,
And i have just upgraded it to `php5.6.28`.

Even if i check my current `php` version it shows **PHP Version 5.6.28** using `http://localhost/?phpinfo=1`.

Here is my Composer.json

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.9",
        "laravel/framework": "5.2.*",
        "illuminate/database": "~5.3",
        "illuminate/support": "~5.3",
        "laravel/cashier": "~7.0"
    },
```

but when i run the command `composer update`  it keep throwing me error that

```
F:\wamp\www\punit\TPG>composer update
You are running composer with xdebug enabled. This has a major impact on runtime performance. See https://getcomposer.or
g/xdebug
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - illuminate/database v5.3.4 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/database v5.3.23 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/database v5.3.16 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - illuminate/database v5.3.0 requires php >=5.6.4 -> your PHP version (5.5.12) does not satisfy that requirement.
    - Installation request for illuminate/database ~5.3 -> satisfiable by illuminate/database[v5.3.0, v5.3.16, v5.3.23,
v5.3.4].
```

Error says that i am using `php5.5.12`.

I want to install **Laravel Cashier**,

Is there any dependency i am missing ?

Comment: What is your php-cli version? Type `php -v` in console.

Comment: you are using wamp right ?

Comment: yes.. i am using wampp

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40478663/composer-not-recognizing-php-5-6-4

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko  -  PHP 5.5.12 (cli) (built: Apr 30 2014 11:20:58)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans

Comment: That is the problem you have the wamp with php 5.6.28 but the php path points PHP 5.5.12 so the confusion

Comment: So you need update your PHP-CLI and will be happy:)

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko Thanks buddy !! , Can you tell me how can i update it  ?

Comment: Sorry dude, I don't know, can advice you update WAMP completely