# I installed php 7.1, but I can't install laravel 5.3 with composer

Tags: php, laravel, wampserver

I have followed to install this tutorial to install php 7.1 in wampserver
http://ryanstelmat.com/upgrading-wamp-server-to-php-7/

I enabled php 7.1 and I see it in phpinfos, but when I want to install latest version of laravel using composer :

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel blog "5.3"
```

I get this error message

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package laravel/laravel with version 5.3 in a version instal
  lable using your PHP version 5.5.12.


create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--r
epository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no
-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vc
s] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<directory>] [<vers
ion>]
```

Like if it doesn't know my latest php version.

How I can fix that?

Thanks

Comment: Try `php -v` on your command line, along with `whereis php`. It may be using the wrong version.

Comment: This might be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673334/composer-to-use-newer-version-of-php

Comment: php -v show me php 5.5.12, and phpinfo of localhost show me php 7.1.0

Comment: Your CLI is pointing to the wrong PHP executable. The second answer in the link I provided should help some.

Comment: you should symlink your php 7 instead php 5 ... your cli not point correct version

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/) to install laravel

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog
```

Comment: it install laravel 5.2 not latest one. when I test with php -v I see php 5.5.12

Comment: php -v will give you the installed php version. Not the laravel version. Open composer.json file and see which version of laravel is installed.

Comment: and one more thing is if php --v shows 5.~, it means, your system is still using php version 5.~ and not php7.1. Try to change the environment variables in windows system settings and make sure php -v shows 7.1

Comment: I have changed my environment path but sitll show php 5: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\ext\imagick;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.0;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;

Comment: try removing the environment variables related to php 5.~ and restart your wamp server.