# Composer telling the wrong php version

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

I know many people are struggling into the "composer using the wrong php version" and the solution is to call composer with the good one (currently suggested duplicate).

Here is my case:

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.6.31 (cli) (built: Sep  8 2017 04:36:13) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies

$ php /usr/local/bin/composer update
  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=5.6.31 but your PHP version (5.5.9)
      does not satisfy that requirement.
```

How can this be explained ?

---

For info, I'm using the official `php:5.6-fpm` docker image.
And I installed `composer` with:

```
$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer
  | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Comment: Sounds like you have your web server using one instance of php, and maybe have a different php in your $PATH, that composer is seeing........?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [composer to use newer version of php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15673334/composer-to-use-newer-version-of-php)

Comment: You could run composer with `--ignore-platform-reqs` to ignore the PHP version, but be aware that this could cause you problems in the long run, e.g. when trying to run the code in the wrong PHP version as well.

Comment: Has the possible duplicate helped solve the question? If so, I will close it. Otherwise, please respond to other comments Pierre and for the possible duplicate not solving it, thank you.

Comment: The suggested duplicate is what I'm talking about in my first sentence, but maybe [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32838881/) can help, I'll check that as soon as I have the time (Related to @dbrumann suggestion)

Comment: can you check in your composer.json? there might be a php version overwrite (symfony skeleton does this for example) see https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#platform
this could also be set in your users config

Comment: That was it ! I just realized that before seing your comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just realized this config at the bottom of my `composer.json`:

```
"config": {
    "platform": {
        "php": "5.5.9"
    }
},
```

That's the version on which it bases his warning (not the one actually used)

Comment: You can change this using `composer config platform.php 5.6`.

Comment: the greatness of this is, so many Composer looking at wrong php versions exist on SO and this needs to be linked to it! Now I have an answer in my dupe arsenal to use!